# Best Practice for Login/Forgot Password Errors?

Tags: privacy, forgot-password

No code question, but rather an application design question. If a user attempts to log in to a web application and provides an unknown username (or email) it seems to be common practice to report back "Unknown username/password combination" or something thereabouts. I.E. it is ambiguous about whether the user got their name or their password wrong.

For "forgot password" pages, it is common to see a request for an email address which the user can use to reset their password. If the user again types in an unknown email address, is it better to show a success page, potentially confusing a user, or show an error page, potentially revealing the fact that the user has signed up for the application. It feels like a privacy concern if I show the error message, but a very small one.

I was personally just affected by this on my development server when I had forgotten that I had recently reset my database. I couldn't figure out why my reset password email wasn't coming through. It wasn't until I finally did a `select *` on my user table that I realized that I wasn't technically even signed up.